# Ferrite bead in Gunn multiplexer

Tags: rf, diodes, inductor, microwave

This [link](https://physicsopenlab.org/2016/03/10/gunnplexer-microwaves/) shows (at bottom of page) a simple Gunn diode circuit. My question is about the "ferrite bead" at the right. It seems to be an inductive coil with increased resistivity (?) near the oscillating frequency of the Gunn diode, in this case 10 Ghz.

Can someone suggest an actual device that corresponds to this circuit element? If I look for--for example--"microwave ferrite beads" I don't see anything obvious. The beads don't seem to be rated in terms of frequency and when they are it's generally MHz vs. Ghz.

Comment: It is a very non-critical component as it is just used to filter the power supply to minimize signals entering from the PSU or going from the circuit to the PSU and potentially radiating via the leads.  The circuit will work fine without that ferrite bead at all, just feed the power directly to the decoupling capacitors.

Comment: @KevinWhite: Thank you. I would have tried this but didn't want to inadvertently wreck the diode.